# How to build a jar from multimudule project?

Tags: java, maven

I have two `Maven` modules in on root module.

```
root
  - module-core
  - module-run
```

`module-run` has `module-core` as a dependency.

How can I build a jar file based on `module-run` with dependencies and manifest?

*UPD*

I use

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.test.app.main.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`maven-assembly-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html). It will by default bundle all of the modules dependencies into the JAR. If you need to restrict it to just module 2, that's trickier but doable... To bundle all dependencies, just add this plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Then you should have said so (I see you updated it now)... and you should say what your problem specifically is. What are you getting that you do not expect/want?